# check if the car location is changed or not

Tags: android, gps

My app is a GPS Tracking App.
 .
  the app running in background to check every 10 sec, if the location is changing or not. if the location changed, the app will send SMS with the new location. if its not it will continue checking.
  My problem is how to check using the last location with the current location detected.
How i can use (If condition ) to see if the last location is still not changing yet.
I want to check if values are the same or not (same location ) to know if the device is moved to another place or still in the location
 in update().

```
                    double a=gps.getLatitude();
                    double  b=gps.getLongitude();
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                         if ( a==Ch1 && b==Ch2){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Changes " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Search();
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Thread thread;
Button btnShowLocation;
double latitude,longitude,Ch1,Ch2;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Search();
    Ch1=gps.getLatitude();
    Ch2=gps.getLongitude();
    update();
}
private void update() {
(new Thread(new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (!Thread.interrupted())
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                {
                    double a=gps.getLatitude();
                    double  b=gps.getLongitude();
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                         if ( a==Ch1 && b==Ch2){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Changes " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Search(); // this action have to be in UI thread
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // ooops
            }
    }
})).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread

}
private void Search() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // create class object
    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);


    // check if GPS enabled     
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

         latitude = gps.getLatitude();
         longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        String sms="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&iwloc=A";
        String number = "012345";

        SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms, null, null);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    else{

        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: `Location.distanceBetween`, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29

Comment: thanks, but I am not trying to calculate the distance between two locations .. I want to check if values are the same or not (same location ). to know if the device is moved to another place or still in the location

Comment: If the distance between the previous location and the current location is less than say 10 meters, you could consider that the user is in the same location.

Comment: It works perfect, It Help me to learn something new, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Location locationA = new Location("point A");
 locationA.setLatitude(a);
 locationA.setLongitude(b);

 Location locationB = new Location("point B");
 locationB.setLatitude(Ch1);
 locationB.setLongitude(Ch2);

 float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```